# Way of keeping library that takes a while to load, loaded using virtualenv type solution for session

Tags: python, import, virtualenv

I use a Python module that interfaces to a programme we use in work. Every time this library loads, it fires up the programme in question and so could take 10-15 s to load. Naturally that is quite some time when it has to be done every time the script is run. It does this when

import moduleToInterfaceToProgramme

is called.

I was wondering is there a way of altering a virtualenv or something similar so that they would load this library once at the start when the virtualenv is activated, and for the duration of the virtualenv being active this library would remain loaded, so that every time it's called in a script it wouldn't need to go through this start up procedure.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Libraries are loaded by processes, not environments. If you can't convert your script into a long-running script that doesn't have to restart, you might need to rearchitect the script into a long-running server (that loads the module) and a client that makes requests for the server to do the actual work.